# Anime featuring a black spaceship in pursuit of a crystalline spaceship across a water planet

Tags: story-identification, anime

When I was about 15 (about 22 years ago) I saw an anime movie dubbed in Spanish, and I've been trying to figure out what it was ever since:

The key things I remember were that a big black spaceship (very cool looking, vaguely angel shaped I think) was chasing or searching for a crystalline spaceship (the good guys) across what seemed to be a water planet.

At one point some friendly magic or psychic aliens levitate the crystal ship out of the sea, but get shot full of holes by the big black ship's gun batteries. The bigger ship has a command bridge, gunnery staff etc, and I think some vaguely Sephiroth-ish blonde guy in the command chair.

The good guys looked a bit like a harem setup, with I think all girls bar one guy. One of the girls might have had a giant wrench?

A few times I've looked back and thought "Surely that was Tenchi or something, right?", and indeed the animation and character design did have that same sort of look....but I've skipped through all the space Tenchi stuff I could find, and none of it matches.

At the end I'm pretty sure the crystal ship started working again (not sure why, let's just speculate "the power of friendship" or whatever), and made the black ship explode and crash, which I'm pretty sure involved the captain going down in his on-fire ship, holding a woman, presumably a love interest.

Comment: 2000 seems like it would be old enough that there won't be very many officially licensed Spanish anime, but I also have no idea where to find this information. Do you recall if you saw it on TV or on a VHS? if TV, any idea of the station? There might be a list of old TV lineups

Comment: Mm, i tried that route a few years ago but didn't get anything useful - it's a good idea tho. I don't know the channel, but it was also showing NG Evangelion and Akira; I can't remember if I figured out which channel it was, in the end...

Comment: An anime from 22 years ago with one guy and a bunch of girls on a spaceship makes me think of Vandread, though I don't think it fits the rest of your recollections.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I checked out Vandread a few times too, but no dice 

Comment: [Here's a list](https://www.anisearch.com/anime/index/page-1?char=all&synchro=es&from_date=1960-01-01&to_date=2001-01-01&category_include=23&sort=date&order=asc&view=4&title=en,fr,de,it,es&titlex=1,2) of sci-fi anime dubbed into Spanish from before 2001.
It's not that long, just look through them. Most of them have screenshots, so that shouldn't be too difficult.